# How to calculate RSA CRT parameters from public key and private exponent

Tags: rsa, public-key, keys, modular-arithmetic

Given the public key (*n*, *e*) and private exponent (*d*), how to calculate CRT parameters (*p*, *q*, *dP*, *dQ*, and *qInv*) of this RSA key pair?

Comment: You may be interested in [this question / answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921406/calculate-primes-p-and-q-from-private-exponent-d-public-exponent-e-and-the) on SO.

Comment: Actually, that answer (despite being given by Thomas Pornin, who is generally accurate) is wrong; $ed-1$ needn't be a multiple of $\phi(n)$.  Actually, Thomas notes this himself; for some reason, he doesn't give the full answer (possibly because he didn't want to get into number theory)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first (and hardest) step is to factor $n$; the easiest way to do this (given $e$ and $d$) is with this randomized procedure:

- Select a random value $z$ from the range $(2, n-2)$
- Compute the value $\lambda = (ed-1)/2^k$, where $k$ is that integer that makes $\lambda$ an odd integer.
- Compute $t = z^\lambda \bmod n$.  If $t = 1$ or $t = n-1$, we fail on this selection of $z$.
- Do this repeatedly, at most $k$ times:

  - Compute $u = t^2 \bmod n$.
  - If $u = -1$, we fail on this selection of $z$.
  - If $u = 1$, we have success (and we have the factorization $p = gcd(n,t-1)$, $q = gcd(n, t+1)$)
  - Otherwise, set $t = u$, and continue with the next loop
- If we run through the above loop $k$ times without hitting either success or failure, then either we happened to have selected a $z$ that's not relatively prime to $n$, or $d, e$ are not a valid RSA exponent pair.

A random value of $z$ will fail at most half the time; so we run this procedure (selecting different random $z$ values) until it succeeds, and gives us the factorization.

Once we have the factorization of $n$, computing the rest of the CRT parameters is straight-forward.

Comment: The $\lambda$ in that calculation, isn't necessarily the usual $\lambda(n)$, right? Only a multiple of it.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: nope, it's just a temporary variable name.